# How do I get the dependency for POI API?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I wish to use POI api to read excel files.
I get the dependency for POI api from Maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I know what else needs to be included in the POM.xml to clear all the dependencies?

Comment: just use `poi-ooxml` and you got everything you need

Comment: I did that. But I get error on line ```if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)```  as ```CELL_TYPE_STRING cannot be resolved or is not a field```

Comment: That is because you are using the old code. That code is pre v4. Update the code

Comment: Oh I see. Let me try to update the code. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Looking into [Apache POI components map](http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components)

[image]

my expectation is that you need to use [poi-ooxml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml) library, Maven [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) feature will get all underlying dependencies automatically so you basically need only this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

An example code to read the file would be something like:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("/path/to/your/file.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
pkg.close();
```

References:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)
- [Running Data Driven Tests](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+Session+7+-+Running+Data+Driven+Tests)
- [How to use the HSSF API](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html)